# google map in fragment activity in Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

When I put the Google Maps API in Fragment, it seems to have started but the application stops and closes.

The last image before the application closes

[image: App Image]

Log Output

```
2019-11-19 14:18:05.137 19795-24984/? E/chph: *~*~*~ Channel {0} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
    at chpg.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):2)
    at chph.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):2)
    at chic.b(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):8)
    at sqq.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):24)
    at sqq.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):33)
    at awdm.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):81)
    at awdm.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):165)
    at awdj.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):2)
    at awdt.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at brav.a(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):2)
    at brcx.b(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):2)
    at brbw.run(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):7)
    at brcz.run(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):1)
    at sxr.b(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):15)
    at sxr.run(:com.google.android.gms@19629028@19.6.29 (100400-278422107):10)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at tdp.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I searched a bit and got another error from the log output

```
2019-11-19 15:08:13.298 4490-4548/com.ourcrewapps.webbil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.ourcrewapps.webbil, PID: 4490
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at ep.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3)
        at eo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):4)
        at eq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):55)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):11)
        at dx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):17)
        at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):65)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):25)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at ep.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3) 
        at eo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):4) 
        at eq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):55) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):11) 
        at dx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):17) 
        at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280052@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):65)
```

Java Class Output [LocationFragment.java]

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap gmap;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location,container,false);
        SupportMapFragment mapci =(SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapci.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gmap = googleMap;
        LatLng lng = new LatLng(19.169259,73.341601);
        gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lng).title("sad"));
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lng));
    }



}
```

XML Output [fragment_location.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Api key added

Comment: Is there any code except above, because it showing ThreadPool Exception. The reason for this is executing a background task on the main thread.

Comment: are you talking about the Log output code ?

Comment: No, I am talking about ** LocationFragment** Class code.

Comment: sorry no just this

Comment: Please verify this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm. Make sure you follow all the given steps.

Comment: okay ,i'm looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has improved. The problem was the library versions and the minimum sdk error

Min sdk

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ourcrewapps.webbil"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Library Version

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In the latest update of Google for Maps, only MapView is supported for fragments.
MapFragment & SupportMapFragment doesn't work. 
I might be wrong but this is what I saw after trying to implement MapFragment & SupportMapFragment.

Setting up the layout for showing the map in the xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

While Add below code in your java file:

public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work  last image of the application before closing https://i.stack.imgur.com/4htAG.jpg

Comment: Override onResume() and put mMapView.onResume() in it. This is working code I suggested you.